# bibtex error message Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. (natbib) Press <return> to continue in

Tags: natbib

```
\documentclass[12pt,roman]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\author{\bf Ray Makondo\\ \bf Reg Number:M121549}
\title{Great Zimbabwe University\\ Faculty of Commerce\\ Department of Economics\\\begin{flushleft}
MODELLING THE RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN UNEMPLOYMENT AND INFLATION IN ZIMBABWE FROM 1980-2014
\end{flushleft}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction and Background}
\section{Indroduction}
One of the fundamental objectives of nations if many is to sustain low level of unemployment as well as inflation.The costs related with inflation are of major economic interest since they determine the level of economic performance of a nation.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibiliography{citation}
\end{document}
```

My database is:

```
@article{Ireland2014,
author = {Ireland, P},
journal = {Manhattan Institute},
title = {{Shadow open market commitee meeting}},
year = {2014}
}
@book{Arnold2008,
address = {San Marcos},
author = {Arnold, R},
publisher = {California State University},
title = {{Economics}},
year = {2008}
}
@book{Gordon1982,
author = {Gordon, Robert J},
booktitle = {Inflation: Causes and Effects},
isbn = {0226313239},
pages = {11--40},
title = {{Why Stopping Inflation May Be Costly : Evidence from Fourteen Historical Episodes}},
url = {http://www.nber.org/books/hall82-1},
year = {1982}
}
@article{Feldstein.S1996,
author = {Feldstein.S},
journal = {National Tax Journal},
title = {{Social Security and Saving: New time series evidence.}},
year = {1996}
}
@article{ZimStats2011,
author = {ZimStats},
title = {{Quarterly Labour Force survey}},
year = {2011}
}
@Article{Cagan,
author = {Cagan},
title = {The monetary dynamics of hyperinflation},
journal = {Economica},
year = {1957}
}
@Article{Fanelli,
author = {Fanelli, L},
title = {\lq\lqTesting the New Keynesian Phillips curve through Vector Autoregressive Models". results from the Euro area.},
year = {2005}
}
```

I am getting an error message and the output gives me mixed reference formats the other are numbered and the other are sorted in square brackets

Comment: have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Well, your given message is caused by some missing `journal` fields and a missing `publisher` field (I added them with `MISSING JOURNAL` etc).  I added them in the following MWE (minimal working example).  A lot of your called packages have nothing to do with your resulting error. I just deleted them.

So please **study** the following MWE and please read the inserted comments in the code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents} % only to have bib file and tex code in one MWE
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ireland2014,
author = {Ireland, P},
journal = {Manhattan Institute},
title = {{Shadow open market commitee meeting}},
year = {2014},
}
@book{Arnold2008,
address = {San Marcos},
author = {Arnold, R},
publisher = {California State University},
title = {{Economics}},
year = {2008},
}
@book{Gordon1982,
author = {Gordon, Robert J},
booktitle = {Inflation: Causes and Effects},
publisher = {MISSING PUBLISHER},
isbn = {0226313239},
pages = {11--40},
title = {Why Stopping Inflation May Be Costly: Evidence from Fourteen Historical Episodes},
url = {http://www.nber.org/books/hall82-1},
year = {1982},
}
@article{Feldstein.S1996,
author = {Feldstein.S},
journal = {National Tax Journal},
title = {{Social Security and Saving: New time series evidence.}},
year = {1996},
}
@article{ZimStats2011,
  author = {ZimStats},
  title = {{Quarterly Labour Force survey}},
  journal = {MISSING JOURNAL},
  year = {2011},
}
@Article{Cagan,
author = {Cagan},
title = {The monetary dynamics of hyperinflation},
journal = {Economica},
year = {1957},
}
@Article{Fanelli,
  author = {Fanelli, L},
  title = {The New Keynesian Phillips curve through Vector Autoregressive Models. Results from the Euro area.},
  journal = {MISSING JOURNAL},
  year = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,roman]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref} % better bibliography

\author{\bf Ray Makondo\\ \bf Reg Number:M121549}
\title{Great Zimbabwe University\\ Faculty of Commerce\\ 
  Department of Economics\\
  \begin{flushleft}
    MODELLING THE RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN UNEMPLOYMENT AND INFLATION IN 
    ZIMBABWE FROM 1980-2014
  \end{flushleft}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction and Background}
\section{Indroduction}
One of the fundamental objectives of nations if many is to sustain low 
level of unemployment as well as inflation.The costs related with 
inflation are of major economic interest since they determine the level 
of economic performance of a nation.
\nocite{*} % to check all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname} % not bibiliography
\end{document}
```

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I get the following result (only bibliopgraphy page):

[image: bibliography page only]

Please change your other question, short your bib file and the TeX code to the relevant part to reproduce the error as I showed you in this answer ...